# Detect if iphone/ipad connected to VPN via public wifi programmatically

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi, vpn

We have an app wherein certain functionality needs to work only when the user is connected to a router associated with his account (we have some information about user accounts and home routers).
However, it is possible for the user to set up a VPN connection to his home router via any public wifi/3g network. We want to block certain functionality if that is the case.

Any ideas as to how it can be detected using any of the existing iphone/ipad apis?

Thanks,
Hetal

Comment: What's wrong with VPN from a public hotspot? The whole point of VPN is that you're protected on insecure networks like that.

Comment: We have a requirement from the powers that be that certain functionality needs to only work on home router and not when you are connected via any public wifi or 3g.

Comment: Might be worth notifying the powers that be that VPN from a public hotspot is massively more secure than non-VPN from a home hotspot.

Comment: Its not just about security. It is about having that functionality being accessible "from any network" can run them into other issues.

Comment: If they're VPNed into their home network, they're on the same network as if they were right there physically at home. That's the whole point of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a flag in the reachability API called kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection.
It is true when you are connected via a VPN and false if you are not connected via a VPN.
We used this flag value to check for our conditions.

Comment: Is that true? kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection just means a transient connection such as PPP. It might be true that WiFi and kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection means VPN but I'm not sure that kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection always means VPN. Other weird network setups like USB tethering or Bluetooth PAN might set this flag.

Comment: It means other things as well e.g. 3G/4G connection. But it worked for our requirement since we didn't have to distinguish between all kinds of transient connections. We just needed to see if any kind of transient connection existed and this worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

There's no iOS API (public at least) that is going to give you information on whether you're running on a home router or public WiFi connection.  You can only determine that you're on a WiFi connection vs. 3G.  (for example, see the [Reachability sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2))

You might be able to do some sort of lookup based on the device's current IP address.  You'd have to have each user register their router's IP address and have your application validate it before running, etc.  But still, there'd be no guarantee that user's home router is secured.  In other words, it could be just as wide open as a public WiFi.